# Rails server will not stop and even if it is running it is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails, but I managed to install it using the RailsInstaller and I am using Aptana Studio 3 as a text editor. I am on a Windows 7 x64.

Last week I managed to create a simple Hello world project, and it worked as it should when starting and stopping the rails server. To start the server I used the command **rails server** and to stop it I used **CTRL+C**.

Somehow, this week, when I'm trying to start the server it says "A server is already running". But, when I go to the correct page in a web browser it doesn't work. I get the error "Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:3010". So, this makes it seem like the server is not working, even though it supposedly is running.

So, I then try to stop the server from running, but CTRL+C doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't give any kind of message at all when I input that, it just skips to a new line in the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

the standard port is 3000.

You can kill the server in the task manager and start it from new..

Comment: I've checked the ports and there is no process using it in the task manager. Must be a bug somewhere else.

Comment: Do you use apache on another project maybe?

Comment: I thought of that too since I do have an apache server, but even after I closed it down, it doesn't work. I think I may have to try uninstalling and reinstalling all the rails stuff and see if that helps.

Comment: and are you sure that there is no ruby or apache process in the task list?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it multiple times, both yesterday and today and I can't find anything related to either ruby or apache. I'm just gonna uninstall everything and hope a reinstall solves the problem. At the very least it can't keep running a server if I uninstall everything, or so I hope.

Comment: whick server are you using? webrick, thin, apache,...?

Comment: Webrick for rails. But, I've reinstalled everything and it seems to be working fine now. Must have been a bug somewhere that I couldn't find. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a rails process still running but bugged out/crashed. Try looking at the processes in the windows task manager to for a rails process, and cancel it. Additionally you can start a rails process on a different port with `rails server -p PORT`

Comment: From what I can tell from the task manager there is no rails process running.

And, I tried starting it using the __rails server -p 3001__ command, but still only get told there already is a server running.

Comment: This may be too obvious, but have you rebooted? I'd be very surprised if your rails server was set to start at boot unless you've set that up explicitly. Additionally, you should try starting a rails server on a port that you haven't used (4000?) just to make sure you can still start one, and that nothing else is wrong.

Comment: I did reboot, many times. I don't think the server was actually running, I just think rails thought it was, because I could find no other indication that it was actually running. Anyway, I reinstalled rails and it seems to be working now. Thanks for your help though